# Change Pawn movement speed

Tags: c++, movement, unreal-4

I'm newbie in Unreal development and I don't know how to move my pawn faster.

By the way, I'm using Unreal 4.16.

I'm developing Pong game and I have this method to move the pawn:

```
void AAIPaddle::MovePaddle(float Scale)
{
    // Add a movement input, hardcoding Z speed to 100.0f
    FVector direction = FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);

    // Scale could be -1.0f or 1.0f or 0.0f.
    AddMovementInput(direction, Scale);
    if (OurMovementComponent &&
        (OurMovementComponent->UpdatedComponent == RootComponent))
    {
        OurMovementComponent->AddInputVector(direction * Scale);
        ZVelocity = Scale;
    }
}
```

You can find the class AAIPaddle [here](https://github.com/ViaCognita/Unreal/blob/master/MyPong/Source/MyPong/AIPaddle.cpp).

I use this `FVector direction = FVector(0.0f, 0.0f, 100.0f);` to set its speed, but I change the value 100.0f with 400.0f or another greater values and it moves with the same speed.

Maybe I haven't understood anything. How can I change its movement speed?

I'm using the following class that inherits from `UPawnMovementComponent`.

```
void UPaddlePawnMovementComponent::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, enum ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction *ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // Make sure that everything is still valid, and that we are allowed to move.
    //      PawnOwner: which pawn owns this MovementComponent.
    //      UpdatedComponent: the component we move and update.
    //      ShouldSkipUpdate: Possibly skip update if moved component is not rendered or can't move.
    // If none own this component or there isn't anything to move or we have to skip this update, then return.
    if (!PawnOwner || !UpdatedComponent || ShouldSkipUpdate(DeltaTime))
    {
        return;
    }

    // Get (and then clear) the movement vector that we set in ACollidingPawn::Tick
    FVector DesiredMovementThisFrame = ConsumeInputVector().GetClampedToMaxSize(1.0f) * DeltaTime * 150.0f;
    // If movement isn't nearly zero
    if (!DesiredMovementThisFrame.IsNearlyZero())
    {
        FHitResult Hit;
        // Move our UpdatedComponent by the given DesiredMovementThisFrame, and sets rotation to
        // UpdatedComponent->GetComponentRotation(), do a bSweep and store any hit on Hit.
        SafeMoveUpdatedComponent(DesiredMovementThisFrame, UpdatedComponent->GetComponentRotation(), true, Hit);

        // If we bumped into something, try to slide along it
        if (Hit.IsValidBlockingHit())
        {
            StopMovementImmediately();
        }
    }
};
```

The project is public in [Github](https://github.com/ViaCognita/Unreal).

Maybe I don't understand something about Vectors.

Comment: GetClampedToMaxSize(1.0f) this is limiting the max size of the vector(aka velocity)and that is why you can't  make it faster.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Westside Tony that GetClampedToMaxSize(1.0f) is limiting the max size of the vector,

you can easily test this by increasing that number for example 
instead of

`FVector DesiredMovementThisFrame = ConsumeInputVector().GetClampedToMaxSize(1.0f) * DeltaTime * 150.0f;`

you can try

`FVector DesiredMovementThisFrame = ConsumeInputVector().GetClampedToMaxSize(200.0f) * DeltaTime * 150.0f;`

or you can manually scale using

`FVector DesiredMovementThisFrame = ConsumeInputVector().GetClampedToMaxSize(1.0f) * DeltaTime * 600.0f;`